# How to overload operator of a nested class?

Tags: c++

I am writing a a linked list and I have an Iterator class within my List class.
I want to overload the = operator but I don't know the correct syntax to start it.

This is what I have in my code

```
class List{
   //member stuff
   class Iterator{
       private: Node* current;
       public: Iterator& operator=(const Iterator& right);
       }
 }
```

I am trying this but I am unsure whether this is correct or not.

```
List::Iterator::operator=(const Iterator& right){
 //stuff
}
```

Can anyone clarify?

Comment: Looks OK minus the missing return type and lack of resolution on the parameter type.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To clarify, your thoughts are correct, but you forgot to have a return type in your function declaration:

```
List::Iterator::operator=(const Iterator& right){
 //stuff
}
```

needs to be

```
List::Iterator& List::Iterator::operator=(const Iterator& right){
 //stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List::Iterator& List::Iterator::operator=(const Iterator& right) {...}
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List::Iterator& List::Iterator::operator=(const List::Iterator& right)
{
    //...
}
```

Comment: Valid, but the function parameter type is already in the scope of class `List::Iterator`.